# Rest API for UCWA how to send Get/POST Requests

Tags: c#, rest

I have to use UCWA rest APIS in one of my project. I have to make a GET request and read the output using C#.

Sample I have received from Documentation like.

Send a GET request on the autodiscovery URL.
The autodiscovery URL can be constructed by appending the domain name to the string "https://lyncdiscover". 
For example, if the domain name is "contoso.com", the autodiscovery URL would be "https://lyncdiscover.contoso.com/".

```
GET https://lyncdiscover.contoso.com/ HTTP/1.1
X-Ms-Origin: http://app.fabrikam.com
Accept: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: https://lyncdiscover.contoso.com/xframe
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: lyncdiscover.contoso.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

How to use httpClient in c# to send such request and read the output.

I have a js code as given below and I have to convert that code for C#.

Javascript code example (from Postman Chrome add-in):

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("grant_type", "urn:microsoft.rtc:windows");
var settings = {
"async": true,
"crossDomain": true,
"url": "https://lynctswebint.MyComp.com/WebTicket/oauthtoken",
"method": "POST",
"headers": {
"cache-control": "no-cache",
"postman-token": "a9kb75b0-e03e-1234-94hi-62861c987654"
},
"processData": false,
"contentType": false,
"mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
"data": form
}
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
console.log(response);
});
```

How can I convert the above code for C#?

Answer (score 0):

Create the Webclient:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient("https://lyncdiscover.contoso.com/");
```

All the other informations can be added as **Headers**. For example:

```
client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
client.Headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
[...]
```

To read the result:

```
string output;    

using(Stream data = client.OpenRead(args[0]))
{
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data))
    {
        output = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have a js code which uses the same api and i have to convert same code for C#. I am updating my question with js code please update if you can help on that.

Comment: @Chandikumar With the help of my answer you should be able to implement the Request in C#. Stackoverflow is not here to convert code from one language to another.